# How to run keyup on specific element?

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have an app in AngularCLI. I am using an ngFor loop on a dataset and searching it with an input field on keyup.  Problem is, my input search function is identical for all iterations so the search happens on all of them. How do I differentiate between each element? Is there a way to make an element active = keyup event? Let me know if you need to see more code.

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of dataset; trackBy: customTrackBy; let i = index">
   <div> 
    <label for="positionCompanyName">Company Name </label>
    <input id="positionCompanyName" (keyup)="$event.target.value && searchCompany$.next($event.target.value)">
     <ul *ngIf="companyResults">
       <a *ngFor="let companyResult of companyResults"> </a>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

The handler :

```
this.searchService.searchCompany(this.searchCompany$)
.subscribe(companyResults => {
  this.companyResults = companyResults
});

// Company Search
searchCompany(terms: Observable<string>) {
return terms.debounceTime(400)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => this.searchCompanyEntries(term));
}

searchCompanyEntries(term) {
return this.http
    .get(this.clearbitUrl + this.queryUrl1 + term)
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: in HTML an `id` must be unique. You can append the index to the `id` to help you identify your inputs, like `id="positionCompanyName_{{i}}"`

Answer (score 1):

Take a `unique Id` and `name` for the `input fields`,

You can do that either using `id` or `index`,

`id="positionCompanyName_{{i}}" name="positionCompanyName_{{i}}"`

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of dataset; trackBy: customTrackBy; let i = index">
   <div>
    <label for="positionCompanyName">Company Name </label>
    <input id="positionCompanyName_{{i}}" name="positionCompanyName_{{i}}" (keyup)="$event.target.value && searchCompany$.next($event.target.value)">
     <ul *ngIf="companyResults">
       <a *ngFor="let companyResult of companyResults"> </a>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just tried adding both `{{i}}` and `{{elem.id}}` and it is not working.

Comment: whats happening now?

Comment: Same thing. Doesn't seem like adding those fields did anything

Answer (score 0):

Pass your search function the element index. Something like:

```
<input id="positionCompanyName" (keyup)="$event.target.value && searchCompany$.next({ val: $event.target.value, id: elem.id })">
```

Instead of `elem.id` (you might not have it), you can use something else unique to the elements, or maybe pass the index (from `let i = index`) so you know which element in the array triggered this.

Now, whatever handler takes this event, will take two params instead of just one, and will be able to focus the search better.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the event in the edit. Where do you suggest adding the elem.id?

Comment: Check my slightly modified answer. Something like this: `(keyup)="$event.target.value && searchCompany$.next({ val: $event.target.value, id: elem.id })"`. Now, whoever is subscribed to `searchCompany$.subscribe()` will get `{ val, id }` instead of just `value`. Where did you subscribe to it? Can you show that part of the code?